# Execution order in Parsec computation

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm having trouble figuring out how to debug my parser written in Parsec. The most curious thing is the order of execution. I have the following code:

```
import Data.Text (pack)
import Debug.Trace
import Text.Parsec.Text (Parser)
import Text.Parsec

material :: Parser MTL
material = do
  name <- many finishLine >> string "newmtl" >> whitespaces >> manyTill anyChar (try finishLine)
  illumCmds <- parseIllum
  texMapCmds <- parseTexMaps
  let mtl = constructMaterial name illumCmds texMapCmds
  traceShow mtl $ return ()
  return mtl

parseMTL :: FilePath -> IO [MTL]
parseMTL filepath = do
  s <- readFile filepath
  case parse (many material) filepath (pack s) of
    Left x -> error $ show x
    Right x -> return x

loadMTL :: FilePath -> IO ()
loadMTL fp = do
  putStrLn $ "Start loading MTL: " ++ show fp
  parseMTL fp >>= print
  putStrLn $ "Finished."
```

In my program, I'm calling `loadMTL` on a file and I'm receiving the following error:

```
lobjview.exe: Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Prim.many: 
combinator 'many' is applied to a parser that accepts an empty string.
```

So I figured that somewhere in my program there was an error and I was hoping that through the use of `trace` I could narrow it down (wherein showing a thunk would force it to be evaluated and it would resolve all previous parsing up until the call to `trace`). However, I'm getting some behavior that I don't quite understand. My output is as follows:

```
... other stuff ...
MTL { ... everything looks good here ... }
... other stuff ...
Loading MTL: filepath.mtl
lobjview.exe: Text.ParserCombinators.Parsec.Prim.many: 
combinator 'many' is applied to a parser that accepts an empty string.
```

So my first question is this:

- Why does my `trace` show prior to the output from the `IO` monad?

I decided to profile my code and run it using `+RTS -xc` to see a stack trace of where this error was coming from. Best guess is this:

```
Text.Parsec.Prim.CAF
--> evaluated by: Lambency.Loaders.MTLLoader.whitespace,
called from Lambency.Loaders.MTLLoader.finishLine.comment,
called from Lambency.Loaders.MTLLoader.finishLine.endMarker,
called from Lambency.Loaders.MTLLoader.finishLine,
```

That corresponds to this code:

```
whitespace :: Parser Char
whitespace = tab <|> char ' '

whitespaces :: Parser [Char]
whitespaces = many whitespace

finishLine :: Parser ()
finishLine = many (whitespace <|> comment) >> endMarker >> return ()
  where
    endMarker = endOfLine

    comment :: Parser Char
    comment = char '#' >> manyTill anyChar (try $ lookAhead endMarker) >> return '_'
```

So my second question is this:

- Is there any way that this code can be causing the error that I'm getting? I don't see how.

## EDIT

The link to my code can be found here:

https://github.com/Mokosha/Lambency/blob/MTLLoader/lib/Lambency/Loaders/MTLLoader.hs#L555

This code runs as I'd expect it to, but I arrived at this solution mostly through guesswork. I'd still like answers to my original questions. The main differences between this code and the code in the question are:

1. `material = do` changed to `material = try $ do`
2. `many material` changed to `many material >>= (\x -> many finishLine >> eof >> return x)`

Perhaps this can shed some light on what was causing the problems in the first place. An example of a data file parsed by this code is as follows:

```
# Default material file.  Created by Morgan McGuire and released into
# the Public Domain on July 16, 2011.
#
# http://graphics.cs.williams.edu/data

newmtl default
  Ns 10.0000
  Ni 1.5000
  Tr 0  0
  illum 2
  Ka 1 1 1
  Kd 1 1 1
  Ks 0.2 0.2 0.2
  Ke 0 0 0
  map_Kd default.png
```

Comment: Could you post the definition of `endOfLine`, or a link to the source?

Comment: It depends so much on what's in your `-- Some stuff here --` section. In the code you have given, `material` only parses the empty string, so applying `many` to it as you have is an error.

Comment: @JohnL `endOfLine` comes from [Parsec 3.1.7](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.7/docs/Text-Parsec-Char.html).

Comment: @luqui I'm not convinced that it does depend on that. I edited my post to include the full code, just to show it doesn't parse only the empty string, but the point of my question is that I don't think that that should matter. Why is the output of `traceShow` show up properly and before the output of the `IO` calls? And since the output of `traceShow` is correct, why is my parser failing with the error it provides?

Comment: @Mokosha: `many` applies its parser multiple times.  I suspect that `material` parses one value correctly, but then `many` calls it again with the empty string, leading to the failure you see.  As for the trace output appearing first, I wonder if it's because `trace` outputs to stderr and your shell simply prints that before printing stdout (buffering may be related as well, or it may be a completely separate issue)?

Comment: I think this is still not obvious. What's `parseIllum` and `parseTexMaps`?

Comment: @JohnL, what do you mean 'calls it again with the empty string'? The parser has a list of characters it accepts next, and the stream should have a next character or `eof` if it's done,  right?

Comment: @kosmikus, my question is why is it not obvious? The implementation of those calls shouldn't matter. The output of `trace` means that those calls succeeded.

Comment: @Mokosha None of your `many` calls look like they provoke the error you see. So I speculate the problem is elsewhere. When asking questions, you should make it easy for others to reproduce your problem. Giving partial programs bit by bit does not help. For example, your sample output mentions `Loading MTL`, but your code fragment prints `Start loading MTL`. To be honest, I don't trust that what you're showing us corresponds to what you're actually running.

Comment: @kosmikus, I avoided including most of the code because I (incorrectly) thought it would make the question more verbose and harder to answer. I've edited my question to better illustrate the issues I'm running into. After changing `material = do` to `material = try $ do` in the question, the code ran fine. I'd like to know why.